# Expected value of size of randomly choosen subset

Tags: probability, expectation

Given a set S such that |S|=n.
Let X - numbers of items in randomly choosen (but non-empty) subset of S. Each subset have the same probability to be choosen. Find E(X).

Comment: Any thoughts?  Easy enough to do this for small $n$, for example.

Comment: Just to say:  the answer comes out a lot cleaner if you include the empty set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $|S| = n$, then there are $2^n$ subsets of $S$.  Since we don't want to include the empty set, we have $2^n-1$ subsets.

Since each subset has the same probability of being chosen, then each one has probability $\dfrac{1}{2^n-1}$ of being chosen.

Note that in the above I assumed that the empty set $\varnothing$ is not in the sample space.  If it in fact is the case that $\varnothing$ is in the sample space then the probability will be $\dfrac{1}{2^n}$ instead.

Let $P(S)$ denote the power set (i.e., set of all subsets) of $S$.  Then
\begin{align}
  E(X) &= \sum_{A \in P(S)} |A| \cdot \frac{1}{2^n-1}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac{1}{2^n-1} \sum_{A \in P(S)} |A|
\end{align}

So the problem essentially comes down to computing $\sum_{A\in P(S)} |A|$, which is the sum of the sizes of all the subsets of $S$.  Can you take it from here?  Note that we don't need to explicitly exclude $\varnothing$ in the sum because $|\varnothing| = 0$ anyway.

Comment: Okey, it is $n\cdot 2^{n-1}$, so answer will be $\frac{n2^{n-1}}{2^n-1}$. Another question: $\frac{1}{2^n-1}$ is a probability density function? If yes, it should be same for any x? There is more subsets with length 2 than with length 1, so i really shouldn't think about it that way?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really remember enough about probability theory to comment on PDFs.